# Disable buttons for emergency call and volume control in lock screen

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens

When you see Android's lock screen, there are still some controls available that may be used without unlocking the phone. For me (Android 2.3.3 - LG version) it's the volume control and the button for emergency calls.

Unfortunately, it has happened a number of times now that, when the phone was in my pocket, it somehow automatically started an emergency call or increased the volume. I don't know how this could happen but ...

The only solution I can imagine is to disable those controls. Is this (easily) possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that LG makes the lock screen configurable like that, but you could always try a lock screen replacement. Something like Widgetlocker or Lockbot might do the trick for you. Lockbot has a free version, so I'd start with that and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you, good idea! But unfortunately, WidgetLocker etc. don't really replace the original lock screen. Instead, they're just a normal app which opens directly, right? They don't offer PIN unlock and the other security options.

Comment: Well, I've played with widgetlocker and lockbot free, and they both pretty much replace the lock screen (turn your phone off and when you turn it back on, there's the new lock screen), and I'm looking at lockbot's options, and it allows you to do password, pattern or (in the pay version) shake to unlock. So as far as I can see, it's a full replacement for the lock screen.